# Java programming for Arduino

Tags: arduino, java

I need to know which technologies should I be familiar with 
to program for Arduino? 
Or knowledge of native Java will be enough?

Comment: No, Java is completely irrelevant to Arduino.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: Migrate to SO.SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is largely irrelevant to Arduino programming. Running Java needs a JVM (Java Virtual Machine), which is, roughly speaking, a combination of an interpreter and a just-in-time compiler for the JVM bytecode language. This needs quite a bit of memory and computing power. I don't know much about that newer ARM-based Arduino, but my guess is that even that doesn't have nearly enough memory and power to run a JVM.

For Arduino programming, the main languages are C and C++ (or rather, a certain subset of C++).

Comment: Although the IDE is written in Java. But that's still pretty much irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

If you know Java then C++ (used by  the arduino ide) will be very easy to pick up.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Java and C++ are marginally similar, and throwing a MCU into the mix just complicates it more.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - no, it does answer the question, by pointing out that the Arduino is C++ based but that this has major similarities to Java which can be leveraged for learning.